# How to run through all subdirectories of a given directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a script that reports on files directly in the present directory. I would like to extend my script so that it runs through all subdirectories and subdirectories of subdirectories and so on and makes an overall report.

for example:

[image]

```
my_script > report
```

creates a report like:

```
HEADERS += \ 
    header1.h \
    header2.h \

SOURCES += \ 
    source1.cpp \
    source2.cpp \
```

But let us imagine we have subfolders:

[image]

I would like to make a recursive report like:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "relative path to subfolder1"

"result of my_script for subfolder1"

INCLUDEPATH += "relative path to subfolder2"

"result of my_script for subfolder2"

HEADERS += \ 
    header1.h \
    header2.h \

SOURCES += \ 
    source1.cpp \
    source2.cpp \
```

I tried to look at similar questions but all of them seemed different in nature and were answered by a one line linux command. I think that my problem is more complicated, since the script needs to call itself recursively.

EDIT: here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ls *.h &> /dev/null; then
echo "HEADERS += \ "
printf '    %s \\\n' *.h
echo ""
fi

if ls *.cpp &> /dev/null; then
echo "SOURCES += \ "
printf '    %s \\\n' *.cpp
echo ""
fi

if ls *.ui &> /dev/null; then
echo "FORMS += \ "
printf '    %s \\\n' *.ui
fi
```

Comment: Can you post the function that you use to generate the listing of one dir? You need to modify it so that when it sees a directory, it enters it and calls itself again.

Comment: Have you tried the [`tree`](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) command?

Comment: @dogbane I also need to execute a script for each directory, not just view the structure, so I think it does not solve my problem.

Comment: if you are not limited to bash, zsh has powerful recursive globbing, that is made for situations like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think that my problem is more complicated, since the script needs to call itself recursively.

Does it need to be recursive, or does it need to be called once for each
directory?  This snippet should allow the latter:

```
find ${top:?} -type d | while read dir; do
    (cd $dir && ${name_of_script:?})
done
```

N.B.: Add suitable values for the variables `top` (top of the tree) and `name_of_script`.
They've been encoded with `${var:?}` to trap unset variables and allow the snippet to fail
gracefully.

Comment: Thank you! The program should go to the maximal possible depth. If I replace name_of_script with my_script I get line 3: top: parameter null or not set.

Comment: `top` would just be to top of the tree.  Note that this snippet does not take care of INCLUDEPATH, but it may help you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over just the subdirectories by adding a trailing `/` to a glob.

```
# When there are no matches for a glob, don't treat the glob literally
shopt -s nullglob

# Recursion is avoided when you have no subdirectories
for subdir in */; do
    printf 'INCLUDEPATH += "%s"\n' "$subdir"
    my_script
done

# Arrays aren't strictly necessary, but make things simpler
headers=( *.h )
if [[ $headers ]]; then
    printf 'HEADERS += \\\n'
    for header in "${headers[@]}"; do
        printf '    %s \\\n' "$headers"
    done
fi

sources=( *.cpp )
if [[ $sources ]]; then
    printf 'SOURCES += \\\n'
    for source in "${sources[@]}"; do
        printf '    %s \\\n' "$source"
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ls -R *.cpp`

-R stands for recursive

Comment: Thank you, but I need to make a report for each subfolder, not just make a listing.

Answer (score 0):

use `ls -lR mainfolder | grep fileextensiontobereported`

Eg: `ls -lR directory1 | grep .cpp`